Conditional Formatting within a Gallery - Power Apps
I have a Gallery that is displaying information from a Collection and I am trying to make it such that 2 of the columns are conditionally formatted based on 2 text labels.
The Gallery is set up from a blank template where each row is made up from Text inputs and is successfully pulling across the information from the collection.
The Gallery is named "Gal_Records"
The Collection is named "Coll_Records"
Which is made up of 4 columns {Name:,Value1:,Value2:,Comment:}
The corresponding Text inputs in the gallery rows are Rec_Name, Rec_Val1, Rec_Val2, Rec_Comment
The Text inputs pull info from the collection through ThisItem.Name etc in the Default property (no Text property available).
I want each Rec_Val1 and Rec_Val2 to be conditionally formatted based on values from Text labels "Lbl_Upper" and "Lbl_Lower" (if Value 1 is between Lbl_Upper and Lbl_Lower, then fill is green, if not fill is red).
I have tried comparing direct to the Labels and also adding 2 additional columns to the collection so there is a comparison within the gallery row, but cant get anything to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Comparing ThisItem to the Text Labels, within the Fill property.
If(And(
ThisItem.Value1.Default<Lbl_Upper.Text,ThisItem.Value1.Text>Lbl_Lower.Text),
"Green","Red")
(I have been using the proper RGBA codes for the colours).
I have also been trying the same using .Text instead of .Default but still not working. I have also tried taking off the .Text from the Upper/Lower Text Labels as well.
I have also tried using the Text input values compared to the Text Labels as well.
If(And(
Rec_Val1.Default<Lbl_Upper.Text,Rec_Val1.Default>Lbl_Lower.Text),
"Green","Red")
*I have also tried to structure the inequalities in the following way with both of the above variations.
*
If(Rec_Val1.Default<Lbl_Lower.Text,"Red",
Rec_Val1.Default<Lbl_Upper.Text,"Green",
"Red")

You can use an expression similar to the one below on your text input controls:
If(
    And(
        Value(Self.Text) < Value(Lbl_Upper.Text),
        Value(Self.Text) > Value(Lbl_Lower.Text)),
    Color.Green, Color.Red)

Notice that to compare with the < or > operators you need to have numbers, so you need to use the Value function to convert the text values from both the text input fields and the labels to numbers before comparing those.
In an example similar to yours, this would result in this output:

It may be worth also checking for errors in case the user enters something that is not a number in the text input controls (or set its Format property to 'Number' to prevent non-numeric values from being entered in the first place).
